# XCode All In One mode not working

Tags: xcode, layout

I've just started iPhone development and I find the workflow to be completely disrupted by the number of windows that opens everywhere.

I read in several places that I could put XCode in a All-In-One mode by closing all projects and then going to Preferences|General|Layout.

So  I did and I saw no improvement what so ever !

Clicking on files still opens a new window for each one(unless I group them), clicking on a .xib file still opens it on no less than three Interface builder windows.

I've tried closing completely xcode, double checking the selected layout, creating a new project in case this setting is project dependent, but to no avail.

I'm beginning to think this layout thing doesn't do what I assume it should.

Any insight would be very welcome.

**EDIT :** Version 3.2.5

**EDIT 2 : Maybe I'm not understanding what this is supposed to do : I thought that when I'd double click on a file(.m,.h.xib) in the project manager it would open the file in the same window. For me it keeps opening new windows for each file. Is that normal behavior in All-In-One mode ?**

**EDIT 3: Ok, last bump before I close this question as a "Nobody has a clue question" :D**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the file you want to edit only once, not twice. Even in Xcode 4, double-clicking on a file in the files and groups list will open the file in a new window, and Xcode 4 is much more "all in one" than Xcode 3.

Comment: Nope that's a no go. When I click on a .m file it shows on the bottom left with a detail view of the file on top right. But if I click on a xib file, nothing happens at all.

Comment: Xcode 3 doesn't have a built-in xib editor, so I'm not sure what you expect to happen. If you double-click on a xib, it should launch open the file in Interface Builder (a separate application). BTW, one reason that you haven't received any other answers could be that most people have switched over to Xcode 4 by now. You might want to do the same -- Xcode 4 has all the behaviors you seem to want.

Comment: I thought I had read that it would open in the same interface. Since I got no answer and can't seem to get what I want you are probably right. I'll get XCode 4 and be done with it. Thanks for your time, I appreciate it.